# Could not load API for android project : how to fix it?

Tags: android, moodle-mobile

The below error message appears when running moodle app on native device.

PS C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\moodle_app> cordova requirements android
Could not load API for android project C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\moodle_app\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js

Comment: Hi! Please check that the platform actually exists in the `platforms` directory (if not, `cordova platform add android` might help). Another thing is to make sure that you're running the command from the actual project's root directory. Then you should check that `cordova --version` is compatible with the version of `cordova-android` module.